# Rails 3.1 - Ajax Radio Buttons

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to add a HighCharts chart to my Rails app, the content of which will be determined by the selection of radio buttons. My code for the radio buttons is fairly standard and is as follows:

```
  <%= radio_button_tag(:interface, "wlan") %>
  <%= label_tag(:interface_wlan, "WLAN") %>
  <%= radio_button_tag(:interface, "3g") %>
  <%= label_tag(:interface_3g, "3G") %>
```

I see Rails 3.1 has the "remote => :true" option to make Ajax much simpler. My question is where exactly do I put this option for a series of radio buttons? I tried adding it at the end of the radio_button_tag parameters, but it didn't generate the appropriate HTML.

Alternatively, if there is a simpler way of doing what I want to do I'd be open to that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using jquery. In my opinion is far easier to do this way.
You put the code in your `your_model.js` file, create the ajax function like the code below.
Create a custom route and do whatever you want.

```
$("#wlan").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "TYPE_OF_REQUEST",
    url: "/your_url",
    success: function(data) {
      ... Your success behavior here ...
    },
    error: function(data) {
      ... Your error behavior here ...
    }
  });
});
```